# Server Sent events with Flask and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn, wsgi, server-sent-events

I've been trying to get a webapp to work which uses Server-Sent Events. The app that I've written works on my local machine when using Flask's `app.run()` method. But when I run it on GAE, I've not been able to make it work.

The webapp uses SSE to publish a message with the current time every so often. The client simply adds it to the HTML of a div.

### Flask app

```py
import random

from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template, Response
from time import sleep

from message_server import app

def event_stream():
    while True:
        time_now = datetime.now()
        message = "New message at time: {0}".format(time_now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        yield "event: {0}\ndata: {1}\n\n".format("listen", message)
        sleep(random.randint(1, 5))


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

### Javascript in `home.html`

```js
var source = new EventSource("/stream");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};

source.addEventListener("listen", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
}, false);
```

### GAE app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --worker-class gevent --threads 10 message_server:app

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

My directory structure is as following:

```
app.yaml
/message_server
    __init__.py
    sse.py
    /templates
        home.html
```

`message_server` is the package that contains the flask `app` object.

I am using Firefox 67 to test my app.

- In the networking tab of Firefox developer console, I see a GET request made to `/stream`, but no response received even after a minute.
- In the GAE logs, I am seeing `"GET /stream" 499`.

How do I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly is `message_server` in your code, I can see you use it both in the `app.yaml` and in your Flask app file.

Comment: @dhauptman Added more information towards end of the question above. Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer while browsing Google App Engine's documentation - on this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled

Essentially, you want the following header in the HTTP response for SSE to work:

```
X-Accel-Buffering: no
```

This disables buffering that is enabled by default. I tested it and SSE is working as expected for me.

Comment: it didn't work for me. Was it in standard or flexible environment?

Comment: `X-Accel-Buffering` no longer appears on the linked page.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/how-requests-are-handled?tab=node.js